# Trying to graph a time series with ggplot2 and getting error

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I am trying to graph a time series, and I run into the error:

> "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.  Error: geom_line requires the following missing aesthetics: y."

Can you please help me understand my error?  Below is the code:

```
set.seed(37)

# Initialize the signal vector for the first model
s_t1 = data_frame(vector(mode = "numeric", length = 400))

# Create the signal vector for the first model
for (t in 1:400) {
  if (t <= 200) { # run if t is at most 200
    s_t1[t] = 0
    } else { # run if t is greater than 200
      s_t1[t] = 10*exp(-(t-200)/40)*cos(2*pi*t/4)
    }
}

# Create the white noise for the two models
w_t = data_frame(e = rnorm(400))

# Create the first model
y_t1 = s_t1 + w_t

# Initialize the signal vector for the second model
s_t2 = data_frame(vector(mode = "numeric", length = 400))

# Create the signal vector for the second model
for (t in 1:400) {
  if (t <= 200) { # run if t is at most 200
    s_t2[t] = 0
    } else { # run if t is greater than 200
      s_t2[t] = 10*exp(-(t-200)/400)*cos(2*pi*t/4)
    }
}

# Create the first model
y_t2 = s_t2 + w_t

s = cbind(s_t1, s_t2)
# Create the time series plot
sPlot = ggplot(data = s, aes(x = t, y = s)) +
  geom_line(stat = 'identity') +
  ggtitle('Signal Modulators') +
  ylab('Signal')
sPlot
```

Comment: `dim(s)` is 400X800. Get rid of `data_frame`.

Comment: Using the code you've supplied `s` doesn't contain any variable (column) names, so there is no `t` (presumably time) to pass to the x axis in `aes()`. As for `y = ` you currently pass `s` to this, but this is the name of the data frame, not a variable.